# How can I make the user switch languages in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a bilingual laravel 5 application that contains two locales, en and ar.

What I want is for the site visitor to be able to change the language of the website by clicking on a link labeled with the language name.

Answer (score 12):

**Option 1:**

1. Store user language in database, I have mine in users table. This is to avoid asking user each time they login to your application.
   You can set 'en' as default. However if user is a guest we store locale in session.

So your migration might look like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('locale', 5)->default('en');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

2. When user or guest clicks on a certain language link then update user locale in database or store guest choice in a session

Example : 
For authenticated user or guest in your controller

```
public function setLocale($locale){
 if(Auth::check()){
     $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
     $user->update(['locale'=>$locale]);
  }else{
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
  }
}
```

3. We need to find a way of setting locale on each request because Laravel does not store locale set with `App::setLocale()` hence we are going to use a Middleware to setLocale on each request.

To understand how Laravel handles `App::setLocale()` here is the method in Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php that handles setting of locale

```
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this['config']->set('app.locale', $locale);

        $this['translator']->setLocale($locale);

        $this['events']->fire('locale.changed', array($locale));
    }
```

This method calls another method in Translator.php show below:

```
/**
     * Set the default locale.
     *
     * @param  string  $locale
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
```

As you can see nothing like caching or session is used to remember locale so we must set it on each request. So lets create a Middleware for it. I will call it LocaleMiddleware.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure, Session, Auth;

class LocaleMiddleware {


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()){
            app()->setLocale(Auth::user()->locale);
        }elseif($locale = Session::has('locale')){
            app()->setLocale($locale);
        }


        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

4. Lets set the middleware to run on each request by adding it to $middleware stack in App\Http\Kernel.php

`protected $middleware = [
            'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
            'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
            'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
            'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
            'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
            'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
            'App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware'
        ];`

Comment: I have stumbled upon this solution, but what if the user is a guest not a registered user, how can I give him the ability to switch languages?

Comment: It seems that I am facing a problem with configuration caching which prevents the application settings to change. . How can I disable configuration caching in laravel 5?

Comment: OK I was trying to clear the cache because I thought laravel is automatically caches the settings but it seems not. 

Anyway I have created a controller that set the locale to ar, but it did not load the string file from the ar folder.

The controller is:
`public function getSwitchLang() {
        App::setLocale('ar');
        return redirect()->back();
    }`
So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Am sorry @wessodesigner App::setLocale() does not really store the default Locale it just set. It simply tells the translator to set it as default and translator does not store it in session so you need to find a way of setting it on each request. I will now modify my answer

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank goodness for your detailed answer. Taylor and co should really update the manual to specify in the localisation part https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization that setLocale does not persist and you have to use middleware. Also note for Laravel 5.5 I had to add this into `protected $middlewareGroups` for `web`.