# Laravel trans helper function not picking the right file

Tags: php, laravel, translation, language-translation, registrar

I'm building a website in Laravel,
I'm having it get the browser language and set the website's language accordingly.

Problem is, nothing in [Registrar.php](http://pastebin.com/RU4C000P) seems to get translated in [English](http://pastebin.com/M7GxeiWM) or [Dutch](http://pastebin.com/djTxJNqQ)

Could anyone please help me out?
Thanks,
g3

Comment: can you show the code of what you have done so far? You need to create separate folders for all languages you want to support and translate accordingly. You can start by coping the contents of resources/lang/en to resources/lang/nl-be, then translate the content of nl-be to dutch

Comment: `Registrar.php`, `English` and `Dutch` are links :)

Comment: how? don't understand, what version of Laravel are you using

Comment: Laravel 5, I mean in the question these are links

Comment: Okay, let me get you right, you wish to change user local when they click dutch link or english link?

Comment: I just saw your code in pastebin, my advice is you should always include your code in your answer to make it clearer, pastebin is good but the link might get broken later and not everyone what to visit pastebin. How are you setting your locale in laravel. If you set Locale properly the correct lang file will be used. I answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723344/how-can-i-make-the-user-switch-languages-in-laravel-5/29726072#29726072

Comment: No, the words I mentioned are in the original question, they link to pastebin with the file's contents. The locale is being set using the browser's configured language. The locale is set the way it should, everything else is being translated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to include everything in the post itself :) Will do so next time :D @DigitLimit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80866/discussion-between-digitlimit-and-g3mini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you need to use a middleware to set Locales:

**Create a `LocaleMiddleware.php` inside `app/http/middleware` directory**

```
//LocaleMiddleware.php

<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Session\Store as Session;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard as Auth;


class LocaleMiddleware {

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session      = $session;
    }


  //Languages available in your resources/lang

   protected $languages = ['en','es', 'nl-be'];



   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       $langlist = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

       // We just want the main language
        $lang = substr($langlist,0,2);

        if(isset($this->languages[$lang])){
           app()->setLocale($lang);
        }else{
           //You may log this here
        }

        return $next($request);
     }

 }
```

**Then register the middleware in `app\httpe.kernel.php` in `$middleware` array**

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,

     .........

    \App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::class,
];
```

**Creating lang files**

You need to create separate folders for all languages you want to support and translate the files in them accordingly e.g `nl-be\validation.php`.

You can start by coping the contents of `resources/lang/en to resources/lang/nl-be, then translate the contents of`nl-be\validation.php` to dutch equivalent

[image]

Comment: I knew how to create lang files :) Might be useful to other's though :D